# Inner and Outerloops

Tags: arrays, excel

Let's say I have two arrays with 4 of the same members. The members are A B C E. Now let's say I want to loop through both arrays to see if there is a match. To do that I had to do the following:

```
For i = 1 to ubound(1st_array)
    For j = 1 to ubound(2nd_array)
      if 1st_array(i) = 2nd_array(j) then
      goto Z
      end if
    next
next
```

Now if there is no match, it seems that Excel will redundantly check certain combinations twice. For example, we only need check the following combinations

AB
AC
AD
AE

BC
BD
BE

CD
CE

But given the way that the function is set up, Excel will check some members more than once. It will also check

BA
CB
CA
DA
DB
DC

And it need not check those. This is not a big problem when we are dealing with arrays of 4 members but it is a problem when we are dealing with an array of 20 members. How do I get around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The pairwise comparison is symmetric. For your example, image there is a 5 x 5 matrix, columns are A B C D E and rows are also A B C D E, you only need to check the lower triangle.

The trick here is to start each inner loop with i + 1. Just modify your code a bit:

```
For i = 1 to ubound(1st_array)
    For j = i + 1 to ubound(2nd_array)
      if 1st_array(i) = 2nd_array(j) then
      goto Z
      end if
    next
next
```

A python 3 equivalent is:

```
s = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]

for i in range(len(s)):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(s)):
        print (s[i], s[j])
```

With the output:

```
A B
A C
A D
A E
B C
B D
B E
C D
C E
D E
```

The code above should be self-explaining. i starts with A, j starts with A + 1 = B and goes down CDE. By next time when i is B, j will only go through CDE but without A, hence we have avoided double checking BA.

Comment: interesting, I think I'll try that out.

Comment: Good answer, but the outer loop need only be `1 to ubound(1st_array) - 1`

Comment: This depends on language. Most languages like Python, the for loop is left inclusive but right exclusive. In that case, the loop variable will run until upper bound - 1, effectively as what you suggest